# sequencing row and column in bootstrap 4.1

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have below structure with rows and columns and I want arrange it in mobile. I have three column in main row and each column have row in vertical. Something like below

[image]

When it comes on mobile I want to arrange Profile than banner, is it possible !! My real code is over here

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/yMT2GFm3mQrpRZHS?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Please somebody help me

Comment: Flex items and grid items need to have the same parent if you want to _really_ reorder them (inserting Banner between Profile and Campaigns). You'd need to use [display: contents;](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/) to magically forget about your columns being the (flex or grid) containers and have grand children (your 4 blocks) be (flex or grid) items of the current parent of your "columns" (e.g. the outer border in your image). [Support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) is not IE/Edge and buggy in Chrome/Safari accessibility wise. I'd relocate in JS ;-)

Comment: @FelipeAls Kindly can you show me same in my plunker, please

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is .
Its called Pull and Push in Bootstrap 3

But in Bootstrap 4 use the flexbox and change the order using order property

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you help me this with my plunker

Comment: OP is using the newer Bootstrap version 4 where push and pull doesn't exist anymore (your link is using Bootstrap 3.3.7, which is the last Bootstrap **v3** ). There's [reordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#reordering) in BS4 but it won't allow what OP is trying to do because the 4 blocks don't have the same parent.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice the version number . In that case you can use bootstrap 4 flexbox and change the order using the order property